# how can i conditionally show questions in amp email

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, email, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I have a react app in which i want to send form to users . I want to show the input field after user selects answer to previous question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html ⚡4email>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
        <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
       <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
        <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
        <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
        <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
          <style amp-custom>
            body {
              font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            }
        
            .hide {
              display: none;
            }
        
            .show {
              display: block;
            }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <form
            action-xhr="https://myapp/api/receiveEmail"
            method="POST"
          >
            <input type="hidden" name="emailId" id="emailId" value="${emailId?.toString()}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="uEmail" id="uEmail" value="${r?.toString()}" />
      
            <amp-state id="questionsState">
              <script type="application/json">
                {
                  "selectedQuestion": 1
                }
              </script>
            </amp-state>
      
            <amp-selector layout="container" name="questionSelector" on="select:AMP.setState({ selectedQuestion: event.targetOption })">
              <div option="1" selected="selected"></div>
              <div option="2"></div>
              <div option="3"></div>
              <div option="4"></div>
              <div option="5"></div>
            </amp-selector>
      
            <template  type="amp-mustache">
              <!-- Question 1 -->
              <section [hidden]="questionsState.selectedQuestion !== 1">
                <label style="font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #333">
                  1. Would you love to partner with KNOTOPIAN for your outsourcing projects?
                </label>
                <h5 style="font-size: 14px; color: #555; margin-bottom: 15px">
                  If Yes, use the calendar to set up a quick sync-up at your convenience to
                  discuss further.
                </h5>
                <input
                  style="
                    width: 100%;
                    padding: 10px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    margin-top: 5px;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    "
                    type="date"
                    name="question1"
                  />
                </section>
        
                <!-- Question 2 -->
                <section [hidden]="questionsState.selectedQuestion !== 2">
                  <label style="font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #333">
                    2. Trust us, you are missing a great deal already! Okay, would you give us
                    a chance to display our portfolio?
                  </label>
                  <h5 style="font-size: 14px; color: #555; margin-bottom: 15px">
                    If Yes, use the calendar to set up a quick sync-up at your convenience to
                    discuss further.
                  </h5>
                  <input
                    style="
                      width: 100%;
                      padding: 10px;
                      font-size: 16px;
                      margin-top: 5px;
                      box-sizing: border-box;
                    "
                    type="date"
                    name="question2"
                  />
                </section>
        
                <!-- Question 3 -->
                <section [hidden]="questionsState.selectedQuestion !== 3">
                  <label style="font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #333">
                    3. Uhm, we still don’t want to miss a chance to let you know how much we
                    can help you! After all, we have a record of creating JAW-DROPPING
                    eLearning in just 7 days! Would you want to know how flexible is
                    Knotopian’s collaboration framework?
                  </label>
                  <h5 style="font-size: 14px; color: #555; margin-bottom: 15px">
                    If Yes, use the calendar to set up a quick sync-up at your convenience to
                    discuss further.
                  </h5>
                  <input
                    style="
                      width: 100%;
                      padding: 10px;
                      font-size: 16px;
                      margin-top: 5px;
                      box-sizing: border-box;
                    "
                    type="date"
                    name="question3"
                  />
                </section>
        
                <!-- Question 4 -->
                <section [hidden]="questionsState.selectedQuestion !== 4">
                  <label style="font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #333">
                    4. Ouch! Give us a FEW minutes and SAVE huge! You won’t regret. Just
                    letting you know our team will be available 24x7 to supporting your needs.
                    Cool, let’s think of the partnership later. But, how about a quick sync-up
                    to just know us better?
                  </label>
                  <h5 style="font-size: 14px; color: #555; margin-bottom: 15px">
                    If Yes, use the calendar to set up a quick sync-up at your convenience to
                    discuss further.
                  </h5>
                  <input
                    style="
                      width: 100%;
                      padding: 10px;
                      font-size: 16px;
                      margin-top: 5px;
                      box-sizing: border-box;
                    "
                    type="date"
                    name="question4"
                  />
                </section>
        
                <!-- Question 5 -->
                <section [hidden]="questionsState.selectedQuestion !== 5">
                  <label style="font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #333">
                    5. We just WON a LearnX Gold Award for one of our innovative learning
                    solutions. Just letting you know! And yeah, we still want to meet you.
                    After all, we both work towards the same goal – Creating Impactful
                    Learning.
                  </label>
                  <h5 style="font-size: 14px; color: #555; margin-bottom: 15px">
                    If Yes, use the calendar to set up a quick sync-up at your convenience to
                    discuss further.
                  </h5>
                  <input
                    style="
                      width: 100%;
                      padding: 10px;
                      font-size: 16px;
                      margin-top: 5px;
                      box-sizing: border-box;
                    "
                    type="date"
                    name="question5"
                  />
                </section>
              </template>
        
              <button
                [class]="questionsState.selectedQuestion === 5 ? 'show' : 'hide'"
                style="
                  background-color: #4caf50;
                  color: #fff;
                  border: none;
                  padding: 10px 20px;
                  font-size: 16px;
                  cursor: pointer;
                  border-radius: 4px;
                  margin-top: 10px;
                "
                type="submit"
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

This is the html i want to embed in my app .However when i send the email , the functionality doesnt work. is there any way i can implement this functionality? i have sent this email to gmail and yahoo . i only want each question to render after user answers previous question